# Can't see my json data in activity in recyclerView , which is saved on web server with url

Tags: android, json

When i run my activity, I am unable to see any `JSON` data from `webserver` in my `recyclerview`, all i can see is a progress bar and after that an empty activity.

i have checked my adapter, i have `setAdapter` in `oncreate` method and have also called `notifyDataChange`.

*VideoLectures.java*

```
public class VideoLectures extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
    RecyclerView recyclerViewFeed;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
    public static final int READ_TIEMOUT=15000;
    public ArrayList<YoutubeVideoModel> youtubeVideoModelArrayList= new ArrayList<>(  );

    public static TextView title;
    public static YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
    public  static TextView duration;
    FirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter;
    VideoAdapter mRecyclerAdapter;


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lectures_video );


       recyclerViewFeed= (RecyclerView)findViewById( R.id.recycler_view );
        recyclerViewFeed.setHasFixedSize( true );
        recyclerViewFeed.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( VideoLectures.this ) );
        mRecyclerAdapter= new VideoAdapter( VideoLectures.this, youtubeVideoModelArrayList, new CustomItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                startActivity( new Intent( VideoLectures.this, YoutubePlayerActivity.class ).putExtra( "video_id",youtubeVideoModelArrayList.get( position ).getVideoId() ) );
            }
        } );

        recyclerViewFeed.setAdapter( mRecyclerAdapter );


        new AsyncFetch().execute(  );

       mRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        ProgressDialog pdLoading= new ProgressDialog(VideoLectures.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url=null;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage( "\tLoading..." );
        pdLoading.setCancelable( false );
        pdLoading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            url=new URL( "https://api.myjson.com/bins/h7z09" );

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return  e.toString();
        }

        try {
            conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout( READ_TIEMOUT );
            conn.setConnectTimeout( CONNECTION_TIMEOUT );
            conn.setRequestMethod( "GET" );

            conn.setDoOutput( true );

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }


        try {
            int response_code=conn.getResponseCode();

            if(response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStream inputStream=conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) );
                StringBuilder result= new StringBuilder(  );

                String line;
                while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    result.append( line );
                }
                return (result.toString());

            }
            else {
                return ("unsuccessful");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return  e.toString();
        }
        finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();


        try {
            JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(result  );

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject=jArray.getJSONObject( i );

                YoutubeVideoModel youtubeVideoModel= new YoutubeVideoModel();
                youtubeVideoModel.title=jsonObject.getString( "Title" );
                youtubeVideoModel.videoId=jsonObject.getString( "YoutubeUrl" );
                youtubeVideoModel.duration=jsonObject.getString( "Duration" );

                youtubeVideoModelArrayList.add( youtubeVideoModel );

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onPostExecute( result );
    }
}

}
```

*VideoAdapter.java*

```
 public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoViewHolder> {

    private  static final String TAG = VideoAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    CustomItemClickListener listener;
    private ArrayList<YoutubeVideoModel> youtubeVideoModelArrayList;




    public VideoAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<YoutubeVideoModel> youtubeVideoModelArrayList,CustomItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
        this.youtubeVideoModelArrayList=youtubeVideoModelArrayList;
        this.context=context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

       LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from( viewGroup.getContext() );
       View view=layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.video_view,viewGroup,false );
       final VideoViewHolder mView= new VideoViewHolder(  view);
       view.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               listener.onItemClick( v, mView.getLayoutPosition());

           }
       } );
       return  mView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VideoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       final  YoutubeVideoModel youtubeVideoModel=youtubeVideoModelArrayList.get( position );

       // holder.videoTitle.setText(youtubeVideoModel.getTitle());
        //holder.videoDuration.setText(youtubeVideoModel.getDuration());
        holder.videoTitle.setText(youtubeVideoModel.title);
        holder.videoDuration.setText(youtubeVideoModel.duration);


       holder.videoThumbnailImageView.initialize( Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener(  ){

           @Override
           public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
              // youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo( youtubeVideoModel.getVideoId() );
               youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo( youtubeVideoModel.videoId );
               youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener( new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                       youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

                       Log.e(( TAG ),"Youtube thumbnail error");
                   }
               } );
           }

           @Override
           public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

               Log.e( ( TAG ),"Youtube initialization failed" );
           }
       } );
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return youtubeVideoModelArrayList!= null? youtubeVideoModelArrayList.size():0;
    }



}
```

*VideoViewHolder.java*

```
public  class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public YouTubeThumbnailView videoThumbnailImageView;
    public TextView videoTitle, videoDuration;


    public VideoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super( itemView );
        videoThumbnailImageView=itemView.findViewById( R.id.video_thumbnail_image_view );
        videoTitle= itemView.findViewById( R.id.video_title_label );
        videoDuration=itemView.findViewById( R.id.video_duration_label );
    }
}
```

This is my xml file having `recyclerview`

*lectures_video.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VideoLectures">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my xml file having layout for each row

video_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:id="@+id/video_title_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"

            android:text="Title of Video"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
            android:padding="10dp"

            android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/video_title_label"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:contentDescription="Thumbnail Image View"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="50dp"/>

       <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/video_duration_label"

           android:text="2:90"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:gravity="end|bottom"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@id/video_thumbnail_image_view"
           android:padding="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you add the JSON data which you are trying to parse??

Answer (score 1):

Try to put notifydatasetchange in onPost method like this.

```
     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

      pdLoading.dismiss();


       try {
         JSONArray jArray= new JSONArray(result  );

         for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject=jArray.getJSONObject( i );

            YoutubeVideoModel youtubeVideoModel= new YoutubeVideoModel();
            youtubeVideoModel.title=jsonObject.getString( "Title" );
            youtubeVideoModel.videoId=jsonObject.getString( "YoutubeUrl" );
            youtubeVideoModel.duration=jsonObject.getString( "Duration" );

            youtubeVideoModelArrayList.add( youtubeVideoModel );

        }
           mRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onPostExecute( result );
}
```

}